# 'com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient' is deprecated

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication, google-authentication

I'm using in my app Google sign-in method and I have updated today my dependencies to:

```
implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-core:17.1.0"
implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:19.0.0"
```

And I stared to get warnings about deprecated classes.

> Warning:(26, 12) 'com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient' is deprecated

And

> Warning:(27, 36) 'com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient.Builder' is deprecated

This is my code:

```
static GoogleApiClient provideGoogleApiClient(Application app) { //deprecated
    return new GoogleApiClient.Builder(app) //deprecated
            .addApi(Auth.GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_API).build();
}
```

My app is still working but how can I get rid of this warnings without the need to downgrade the versions?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Yeah GoogleApiClient has been deprecated.

As per the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/api-client):

> When you want to make a call to one of the Google APIs provided in the
>   Google Play services library (such as Google Sign-in and Drive), you
>   need to create an instance of one the API client objects, which are
>   subclasses of GoogleApi

Particularly for the authentication api, you now need to use `GoogleSignInClient`.

```
    // Configure sign-in to request the user's ID, email address, and basic
    // profile. ID and basic profile are included in DEFAULT_SIGN_IN.
    GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
            .requestEmail()
            .build();

    // Build a GoogleSignInClient with the options specified by gso.
    mGoogleSignInClient = GoogleSignIn.getClient(this, gso);
```

You may refer following documentations for more details:

- [Integrating Google Sign-In into Your Android App](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/sign-in)
- [Moving Past GoogleApiClient](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2017/11/moving-past-googleapiclient_21.html)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. So can I convert my code to be used with `GoogleSignInClient`?

Comment: Oh, it worked, thank you so much. One more small question please, when I used `GoogleApiClient`, in my `MainActivity` I was always `googleApiClient.connect();` in the `onStart()` and `googleApiClient.disconnect();` in the `onStop()`. Is this still required?

Comment: The GoogleApiClient has many functions though that don't seem to exist for GoogleSignInClient though. How do you deal with those? Examples: blockingConnect, isConnected,clearDefaultAccountAndReconnect,disconnect . Also this function uses it: Auth.GoogleSignInApi.silentSignIn()

Answer (score 0):

```
GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN).build();
GoogleSignInClient mGoogleSignInClient = GoogleSignIn.getClient(this, gso);
GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient = mGoogleSignInClient.asGoogleApiClient();
```

There is a nice article on why you should move on from GoogleApiClient as it has several pitfalls. https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2017/11/moving-past-googleapiclient_21.html

Answer (score -1):

```
package com.friendsbike;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat;
import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity;

import android.Manifest;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

import com.firebase.geofire.GeoFire;
import com.firebase.geofire.GeoLocation;
import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationServices;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;

public class CustomerMapActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback,
        GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener, LocationListener {
    private static final String TAG = CustomerMapActivity.class.getCanonicalName();
    private GoogleMap mMap;
    private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient ;
    Location mLastLocation;
    LocationRequest mLocationRequest;
    private Button mLogout, mRequest;
    private LatLng pickupLocation;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_customer_map);
        // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);

        mLogout = (Button) findViewById(R.id.logout);
        mRequest = (Button) findViewById(R.id.request);
        mLogout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signOut();
                Intent intent = new Intent(CustomerMapActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();
                return;
            }
        });
        mRequest.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String userId = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();
                DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("customerRequest");
                GeoFire geoFire = new GeoFire(ref);
                geoFire.setLocation(userId, new GeoLocation(mLastLocation.getLatitude(), mLastLocation.getLongitude()));

                pickupLocation = new LatLng(mLastLocation.getLatitude(), mLastLocation.getLongitude());
                mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(pickupLocation).title("Pickup Here"));
                mRequest.setText("Getting Your Ridder...");
            }
        });
    }


    /**
     * Manipulates the map once available.
     * This callback is triggered when the map is ready to be used.
     * This is where we can add markers or lines, add listeners or move the camera. In this case,
     * we just add a marker near Sydney, Australia.
     * If Google Play services is not installed on the device, the user will be prompted to install
     * it inside the SupportMapFragment. This method will only be triggered once the user has
     * installed Google Play services and returned to the app.
     */
    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;
        buildGoogleApiClient();
        mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);

    }

    private synchronized void buildGoogleApiClient() {
        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this).addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                .build();
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        mLastLocation = location;

        LatLng latLng = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));
        mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(11));

    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onConnected(@Nullable Bundle bundle) {
        mLocationRequest = new LocationRequest();
        mLocationRequest.setInterval(1000);
        mLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(1000);
        mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
        if(ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED &&
                ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) !=PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            return;
        }
        LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest, (com.google.android.gms.location.LocationListener) this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {


    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult) {

    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Your answer looks like to a complete application, whereas, if this is answering the originators question, you should put in some helpful comments.