# Is it still necessary to call GoogleApiClient connect() and disconnect()?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication, google-authentication

I know that `GoogleApiClient` is deprecated and the new class that should be used is `GoogleSignInClient`, as explained by Paresh Mayani in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57575974/10595165). However, when I used GoogleApiClient in the back, in my MainActivity I was always calling:

```
googleApiClient.connect();
```

In the onStart() and:

```
googleApiClient.disconnect();
```

In the onStop().

> Is this still required?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both `GoogleApiClient` and `GoogleSignInClient` are different. Since you are using `GoogleSignInClient`, it is not necessary to connect/disconnect `GoogleApiClient`

**Also for reference:**

> GoogleApiClient is used with a variety of static methods. Some of
>   these methods require that GoogleApiClient be connected, some will
>   queue up calls before GoogleApiClient is connected; check the specific
>   API documentation to determine whether you need to be connected.

This is the demonstration of how GoogleAPIClient works internally
[image: This is the demonstration of how GoogleAPIClient works internally]

**Reference link:** https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/common/api/GoogleApiClient

As recommended by the Google APIs for Android documentation, please migrate to GoogleApi. Following is the migration link:

**Migration Link:**
https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/common/api/GoogleApi

I hope this helps.

Comment: I've read the docs and I still don't understand. So it is still required or not? Thanks

Comment: It totally depends on the functions that you are using of the `GoogleApiClient`, if that specific method needs connectivity as a pre-requisite, then you need the `GoogleApiClient` to be in `connected` state. I would suggest that you should keep the `GoogleApiClient` in connected state that way you will be able to use all the methods that needs the `GoogleApiClient` to be either connected or not connected.

Comment: Voted-up for your answer and comment but I still don't get it. In the past, I was using GoogleApiClient, now there is nothing in my project related to that due the fact that I'm using the `GoogleSignInClient` class. Using only this class, is it still required to maintain some connection or not? Does this practice need to connect/disconnect when the app starts/stops?

Comment: Thanks for the up-vote. Yes, it is important to connect and disconnect the `GoogleApiClient ` with respect to the Activity/Fragment's life cycle. Because `GoogleApiClient` is a wrapper that connects your app to the services that are bundled with `Google Play Services` and `Google Sign-in` is one of them. I have also edited the answer, for your connivence.

Comment: I think you don't understand what I mean. I'll try it again. According to your comment, I know't is important to connect and disconnect the `GoogleApiClient`, I used it till yesterday but NOT I'M NOT USING ANYMORE. So let's don't talk about it. Now I'm using **only** the GoogleSignInClient class., is it still required to maintain some connection or not? Does this practice need to connect/disconnect when the app starts/stops with respect to the Activity/Fragment's life-cycle.?

Comment: Ok, I got it now. Both `GoogleApiClient` and `GoogleSignInClient` are different. Since you are using `GoogleSignInClient`, it is not necessary to connect/disconnect `GoogleApiClient`.

Comment: Ok, thank you so much for answering my question, I'm good now. Please update your answer with some relevant informations from the docs so I can accept it.

Comment: Sure, I am updating my answer.